# Function making dictionary not to work properly

Tags: python, dictionary

this is the first time i work with dictionaries, so i figure out that making a function to append lists to a value that is a list, will make my code cleaner. So i ended up with the mkdir function. But whenever i used the dictionary doesn't work as i expect.

Here is the whole code.

```
# with this the code works properly
pfDirWp = {'l1': [[[0,0],[0,0]],[[0,0],[0,0]]],'l2': [[[0,0],[0,0]],[[0,0],[0,0]]], 'l3': [[[0,0],[0,0]],[[0,0],[0,0]]]}

# using this it doesn't
pfDir = {'l1': [],'l2': [], 'l3': []}

ixP = 1


def mkdir(_dir,iterator,formula):
    for k,v in _dir.items():
        for n in range(iterator):
            v.append(formula)


def addOn(_dir,ixL,boolean):
    if boolean:
        _dir[ixL][ixP][0] += 1
        _dir[ixL][ixP][1] += 1


foo_lst = [[0,0],[0,0]]
# why does this function causes trouble
mkdir(pfDir,2,foo_lst)

print('')
for k,v in pfDir.items():
    print(f'{k}: {v}')

addOn(pfDir['l2'],0,True)



print('')
for k,v in pfDir.items():
    print(f'{k}: {v}')
```

When i run the code as it is, the first print stament shows this:

```
l1: [[[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]]
l2: [[[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]]
l3: [[[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]]
```

This is correct
But after **addOn** function this happens:

```
l1: [[[0, 0], [1, 1]], [[0, 0], [1, 1]]]
l2: [[[0, 0], [1, 1]], [[0, 0], [1, 1]]]
l3: [[[0, 0], [1, 1]], [[0, 0], [1, 1]]]
```

It changes the values of the entire dictionary, i found out that when you don't use the mkdir function and use the values of **pfDirWp** dictionary this doesn't happens instead the final output is this:

```
l1: [[[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]]
l2: [[[0, 0], [1, 1]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]]
l3: [[[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]]
```

That is the correct output.
Do i always have to declare the values of each key before using it, as with **pdDirWp**?
Is something i'm missing or doing wrong, i really want to use the mkdir function.

Comment: ``mkdir`` receives only *one single* ``formula`` object that gets appended to various lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are appending the same 'formula', to solve this you need to make a deepcopy of the list, like:

```
from copy import deepcopy

def mkdir(_dir,iterator,formula):
    for k,v in _dir.items():
        for n in range(iterator):
            v.append(deepcopy(formula))
```

You can learn more on this subject here: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/copy.html

Answer (score 1):

Python handles function arguments differently from several other languages in that almost every function argument (depending on if it's mutable or immutable) is, essentially, "passed by reference" (It's not actually the same as passing by reference but the details on that are explained in many other places and are outside the scope of this question).

So what's happening is you're appending a copy of the same list to each entry in the dictionary, so your dictionary essentially ends up looking like this:

```
{
  l1:[<formula>, <formula>],
  l2:[<formula>, <formula>],
  l3:[<formula>, <formula>],
}
```

What this means is that all your dictionary keys are pointing at the SAME OBJECT (that `formula` object) so when you modify said `formula` object like you are in `addOn` and then try to display the output, since each key is pointing to the same modified object they all display the same output.

There are a couple of ways to solve this issue that I can think of off the top of my head:

- Do a deep copy as was mentioned previously
- Declare your formula inside the lower for loop of `mkDir` function so that it is scope limited for each iteration you want to use it for

I'm sure there are many others but essentially you need to make sure that your dictionary keys are all pointing at different objects if you want this to work.